# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getLong() at GET request

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, web

Good afternoon,

I am with a problem for a few time that I have tryed a lot to find a solution, but I couldn't.

Firstly, my problem derives from `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getLong()`. But, like I said, I haven't been able to solve it, because every aswers tells about trying to get a variable with type is `VARCHAR` at database like a `Long` type variable. However, looking at scope of the models classes I did, all variables is well-typed.

I am working at a Spring Boot Restfull application, therefore, I coded model, repository and resource classes.

I use Postman to test and when I send a `GET` request to a specific resource class I receive that exception, although I have used the same logic to code others resouces, which works.

One of my attempts was change the value, that is inserted at database, from a alphanumeric string, like "Pessoa 1 Reu", to a numeric string, like "1", and the `GET` request was succesfull.

This problem occurs with a relationship class, which relates one relationship class and an entity class, despite `GET` requests being succesfull at each one saparately.

The `GET` resource class method uses a instance of a repository class I did, like others, which calls the `findAll()` method.

I would feel indebted if anyone could help me...

---EDIT---
I add the `CREATE TABLE`'s code at the end of this post. 
The variable which make `GET` requests works is `cpf_cnpj_pessoa`, in `pessoa_fj` table, that is typed as `VARCHAR` in database and `String` in application. And when that variable stores alphanumeric strings,`GET` requests are going to fail...

The Relationship class:

```
//imports was suppressed
@Entity
@Table(name = "reus_advogados")
@IdClass(Reu_AdvogadoIdClass.class)
public class Reu_Advogado {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu")
    protected String cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu;
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="num_processo_reu")
    protected Long num_processo_reu;
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="num_adv_oab")
    protected String num_adv_oab;

    @JoinColumns(value = { 
            @JoinColumn(name= "num_processo_reu", insertable = false,updatable=false), 
            @JoinColumn(name= "cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu",insertable = false,updatable=false) })
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Reu reu;

    @JoinColumn(name="num_adv_oab",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Advogado advogado;

        // Getters, Setters, Hash and Equals was suppressed 
}
```

Exception:

```
2018-09-05 15:24:26.446 ERROR 6800 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid value for getLong() - 'Pessoa 1 Reu'
2018-09-05 15:24:26.451 ERROR 6800 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getLong() - 'Pessoa 1 Reu'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2724) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2653) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2738) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.DiarioDaJustica.api.resource.Reu_AdvogadoResource.listar(Reu_AdvogadoResource.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

The Create Table code:

```
CREATE TABLE processos(
    num_processo BIGINT(16) NOT NULL,
    nome_classe VARCHAR(100),
    num_processo_origem BIGINT(16) DEFAULT 0,
    escrivania VARCHAR(200),
    numero_acordao VARCHAR(15),
    procedencia VARCHAR(200),
    grupo VARCHAR(5),
    relator VARCHAR(200)
);
CREATE TABLE pessoas_fj(
    cpf_cnpj_pessoa VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    nome_pessoa VARCHAR(200)
);
CREATE TABLE advogados(
    num_adv_oab VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    cpf_adv VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    uf_estado_oab VARCHAR(2),
    sigla_pais_oab VARCHAR(4),
    nome_setor VARCHAR(20),
    is_procurador BIT(1) DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE reus(
    cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    num_processo_reu BIGINT(16) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE reus_advogados(
    cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    num_processo_reu BIGINT(16) NOT NULL,
    num_adv_oab VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE processos ADD CONSTRAINT processos_pk PRIMARY KEY ( num_processo );
ALTER TABLE pessoas_fj ADD CONSTRAINT pessoas_fj_pk PRIMARY KEY ( cpf_cnpj_pessoa );
ALTER TABLE advogados ADD CONSTRAINT advogados_pk PRIMARY KEY ( num_adv_oab );
ALTER TABLE reus ADD CONSTRAINT reus_pk PRIMARY KEY ( cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu, num_processo_reu );
ALTER TABLE reus_advogados ADD CONSTRAINT reus_advogados_pk PRIMARY KEY ( num_adv_oab, cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu, num_processo_reu );

ALTER TABLE reus ADD CONSTRAINT reus_fk_pessoa_fj FOREIGN KEY ( cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu ) REFERENCES pessoas_fj ( cpf_cnpj_pessoa );
ALTER TABLE reus ADD CONSTRAINT reus_fk_processo FOREIGN KEY ( num_processo_reu ) REFERENCES processos ( num_processo );

ALTER TABLE reus_advogados ADD CONSTRAINT reus_advogados_fk_reus FOREIGN KEY ( num_processo_reu, cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu ) 
    REFERENCES reus ( num_processo_reu, cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu );
ALTER TABLE reus_advogados ADD CONSTRAINT reus_advogados_fk_adv FOREIGN KEY ( num_adv_oab ) 
    REFERENCES advogados ( num_adv_oab );
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, your request requires 3 keys, one of them is Long. It seems there is a mix of parameters : what you meant as being a string parameter is actually used by Spring data/JPA/hibernate to feed the Long key. Is it possible to post the full code in some Git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!
The problem origins from the following code:

```
@JoinColumns(value = { 
            @JoinColumn(name= "num_processo_reu", insertable = false,updatable=false), 
            @JoinColumn(name= "cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu",insertable = false,updatable=false) })
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Reu reu;
```

In `@JoinColumns` annotation, the order was declared the `Reu` table keys was wrong. When I changed, the problem was solved. The solution is below:

```
 @JoinColumns(value = { 
            @JoinColumn(name= "cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu",insertable = false,updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name= "num_processo_reu", insertable = false,updatable=false)})
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Reu reu;
```

I believe the order, explicited there, have to be the same is shown when you call `desc reus` on database, which `cpf_cnpj_pessoa_reu` comes first. But I am not sure...

I decided to put my solution here because other people may be with the same problem as me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Column(name="num_processo_reu")
protected Long num_processo_reu;
```

> One of my attempts was change the value, that is inserted at database, from a alphanumeric string, like "Pessoa 1 Reu", to a numeric string, like "1", and the GET request was succesfull.

Look in the database schema.  This column `num_processo_reu` is defined as `VARCHAR` and not numeric.  When the value is a string representation of a number, the database did the conversion for you.  When you attempt to read a non-numeric value like `Pessoa 1 Reu` you get the exception because the database cannot convert that value into a a number.

Either change the database schema (i.e. the `CREATE TABLE`) so that column is numeric and cannot contain string values, or change your code to

```
@Column(name="num_processo_reu")
protected String num_processo_reu;
```

And write logic to handle non-numeric values per your project's requirements.

Comment: I forgot to write the "create table" code, I will edit the post and put there. "num_processo_reu" is a bigInt variable in database, so, I had to make a Long variable in application. I can insert alphanumeric string normaly at database, but not in this variable, I will try to explain on edit... Sorry for my forgetfulness